# Запрос на сервер методом TCP/IP с помощью PHP

Tags: php, сокет, tcp-ip

Здравствуйте. Можно ли с помощью PHP осуществить запись на сокет, по протоколу TCP/IP?
В документации описано, что в начале необходимо отправить заголовки, которые собираются побайтно. Т.е. указан тип данных, число или строка, размер и смещение.

Например:
длина сообщения - смещение 0, размер 4 байта
текущее время - позиция 4, размер 4 байта.

Покажите пожалуйста пример если возможно.
Сервер не принимает запросы типа POST, GET.

Comment: Еще в документации сказано, "упорядочить как network byte order"

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Примеры работы с tcp можно на [офсайте посмотреть](http://php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php). А post/get - это http-протокол, который поверх tcp/ip проложен. Т.е. при желании можно самому реализовать поддержку post/get запросов (если tcp-сервер ваш)

Answer (score 1):

Ну и язык вы выбрали, для работы с бинарным протоколом ... php немного не для этого все таки предназначен. Попробую написать как я это вижу, код не проверял ...

```
<?php
  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Создаем TCP Socket
  $ret = socket_connect($socket, "198.51.100.1", 1234); // Устанавливаем соединение с портом 1234 хоста 198.51.100.1
  if(!$ret): print("error connecting"); die(); endif;
  $length=8; // Длина пакета, или что за длину предполагает описанный вами протокол
  // pack упаковывает наши данные в двоичном виде, 'N' - 32 бит big-endian (сетевой порядок байт)
  // Два 32 бит поля, следовательно две 'N'
  $bindata=pack("NN",$length,time());
  $ret = socket_send($socket,$bindata,$length); // Отправляем $length байт из $bindata
  if($ret!=$length): print("Error send data"); die(); endif;
  socket_close(); // Закрываем сокет
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Длина, как я понял из документации, это длина байта (4 бит, 8 бит), тоже точно не знаю.

Кстати, язык выбрал не я, а вышестоящие люди на работе))

Comment: Нет, ошибся, длина в байтах